# Using datatriggers to set the ItemsSource property in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have been trying to set the item source of a WPF control based on a enum that the data trigger is bound too.

I have been very unsucessful and I am unsure of this is the correct way to do it:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EnumSetting}" Value="Test">
      <Setter TargetName="control" Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Model}" />
</DataTrigger>
```

I have been trying different versions of the above. Could anyone help or point me in the right direction.

Should it be wrapped in "<'style'>" tags for example, I don't think it should be but I am unsure why this is not working.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Mainly you need to watch [DP precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which means you may not set the ItemsSource on the `ItemsControl` (or sub-class of that) directly as it would override the trigger. Instead you should use a default setter.

```
<ItemsControl>
     <ItemsControl.Style>
          <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
               <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="SomeDefaultHere"/>
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger ...>
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="SomeOverrideHere"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
</ItemsControl>
```

(You probably want a style unless you are in some control template's triggers.)